# trigger a action based on the presence of families of products using rules?

Tags: commerce, rules

How would I trigger a action based on commerce_product_calculate_sell_price if families of products (or quantities of families of products) are present using rules?

For exemple, if the cart contains products (or a quantity x of products) where the sku starts whit Mx67 (e.g. Mx67b, Mx67er, etc.), NQ-12, etc., when calculating the price do action CalculateX.

Would it be simpler to pass the full list of line items to an action and test for the falilies there? How do I pass the full list of line items to an action and how do I define that parameter in my hook_rules_action_info()?

Thx

Comment: Here : drupal.org/node/2756847#comment-11352641